# Playback lag when displace modifier keyframed (pictures)

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view, keyframes, displacement

I'm having a rather confusing problem. Playback in the viewport (material preview) is great (full 24fps, no lag), but only as long as I don't have any keyframes on a displace modified I'm using.

However, I'd like to animate the displace modifier's strength using keyframes, but as soon as I place one keyframe on the strength of the modifier, my playback drops to 1-2fps.

I have attached a screenshot so you can see my situation. Thanks very much for time and assistance.

[image: screenshot of modifier keyframe and subsequent lag]

Comment: There is a common misconception about the _Frame Rate_ you can set in the _Output Properties_ and the playback speed you see in the viewport. The frame rate in fps you set is for the **output** (which is why you can set them there) and Blender uses it in simulations as well as a reference on how quick or slow a simulation should run since it tries to simulate real-life physics (but you can vary it from the fps with speed/time settings in the physics properties).

Comment: Now that the frame rate is the desired animation speed, Blender will also try to run animations in the viewport with this fps setting. However, especially in very complex scenes, it is not always possible for Blender to calculate the animation quickly enough to go from frame to frame in the time it would take to meet the set fps. In your scene for example, the displacement is quite expensive computational, so if you at first enable it it might take a short while until it is displayed. But now that it's calculated you might be able to play it back with the correct fps.

Comment: But you want to animate the strength of the displacement which means, on any change of the strength from one frame to the other, Blender has to recalculate the displacement over and over again - and this is slower as the time from one frame to another at certain fps. So in order to get to see the animation at the correct fps you could either try to set _Playback_ > _Sync_ to _Frame Dropping_ instead of _Play Every Frame_ (but this only helps a little if any) or make the animation less complex or deactivate everything you don't to preview... or render a _Viewport Render Animation_ as preview.